# Laravel models and fields containing serialized array

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Let's say I have a model "Product", which is linked to the "products" table. This table has a text field "info", which contains a serialized array. I'm happy for this array to be serialized as json, php serialization, or any other way.

Does Laravel have a built in way for me to access the values stored in json? Ideally I'd like to access them in some way like this:

```
$product->info->price
```

Sample array:

```
"price" => "6.00",
"sellby" => "2018-02-05"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does in fact. You can create json type table columns and then cast the column to an array in the model.

```
protected $casts = [
   'column_name' => 'array'
];
```

Edit: Fixed syntax